# Levels of clustered standard errors and fixed effects

Tags: standard-error, fixed-effects-model

A while ago I read (probably on stata forums) that FE can be on a lower level than SE clusters, but not vice versa. For example, firm/household FE with industry/state SE are good, but doing state FE with household SE would be wrong.

Intuitively it seems to make sense. If treatment assignment is on a household level, shouldn't household FE be the first choice? But it seems that there are papers in different fields that use higher level FE with lower level SE. What am I missing?

Comment: From a design based perspective, standard errors need to be clustered at the level that the sample is clustered, i.e. if your sample is clustered at the county level then you need to cluster your standard errors at the county level.

Answer (score 0):

You can always have fixed effects at any level higher than all of the clustering / random effects.

Imagine that you fit a regression to a single state, with random effects or clustering at the household level. That is certainly a valid regression.

Now imagine that you do the same for each state. The regression constants have now become fixed effects for each state! (Okay, you have to estimate the variance and that becomes a pooled estimate rather than estimated separately in each regression. but that doesn't change whether it's valid).